# Weka PART algorithm output

Tags: machine-learning, weka, association-rules

I am using Weka PART on my data set, and it is providing the rules below:

```
Attribute0 > 765.012954 AND Attribute1 <= 141.732431: Unsafe (143.0/1.0)
Attribute0 > 765.012954 AND Attribute3 > 163.157393 AND Attribute0 > 773.571142: 
       Unsafe (65.0)
```

I am able to understand the rules, but I am unable to understand what the double values at the end of each rule mean. Can anyone please explain that to me?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of $(A/B)$ is as follows:

- A: the total number (weight) of instances covered by the rule
- B: the number (weight) of misclassified instances

If all weights are 1 and there are no missing values, the fractional part will always be zero, like $(143.0/1.0)$.
Otherwise, double values may occur. Take care how you interpret these values!

Comment: Just to clarify, the (65.0) means the same as (65.0/0.0)  that is 65 points covered by the rule,  zero misclassified